# One plus five is four?

Tags: riddle

First puzzle! Might be a little easy... :P

> Real life has you feeling bore,
>
> or maybe you puzzle to feel alive.
>
> Must it all be just a chore?
>
> A fake world is where some thrive,
>
> no meaning in our human core.
>
> No matter, the poetry you can ignore.
>
> Uncover discover when one plus five,
>
> makes the number four.
>
> Someone I'm sure, the answer will derive.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Is it :

> **I** + **V** = **IV**

which is

> In Roman numerals, One + Five = Four.

Comment: @humn :) It is a very easy question if someone has been [playing with numbers recently](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/35816/1766)...

Comment: There is a clue in the question about this too. If you read the first letter of each line then you get 'RoMAnNUmS' which can be read as "Roman numbers"

Comment: @manshu Aah, the acrostics, love them :D

Comment: Glad someone noticed the clue ;)

Comment: @aznbanana9 Thank you but it was only after manshu's comment here :)

Answer (score 23):

Yet another possible answer would be

> [(bitwise) XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Bitwise_operation)

which can be viewed as addition in

> a number of algebraic structures of [characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)) 2, including the [nimbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber), the [Galois fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) GF(2<sup>*n*</sup>), and more generally any algebraic system that can be viewed as a [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)) over the two-element [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) ℤ/2ℤ of integers [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) 2,

is often written with the symbol

> ⊕ (a circled + sign, to distinguish it from ordinary addition),

and has the property that

> 1 ⊕ 5 = 001<sub>2</sub> ⊕ 101<sub>2</sub> = 100<sub>2</sub> = 4.

And it even fits the rhyme!

Comment: This didn't get the green tick, and clearly ABcDexter's solution is what the OP intended (the acrostic RoMAnNUmS spotted by manshu shows that), but still +1 for reminding us of an alternative arithmetic which has great puzzling possibilities.

Comment: I was sure there'd be alternate solutions and included the clue for that reason, but nevertheless a great answer!

Comment: Great, this answer shows a lot more effort and Mathematics involved :)

Answer (score 7):

Might not be the correct answer, but you will like this:

> Minus **one plus five is four**. Yes it is!
>  -1 + 5 = 4

Answer (score 6):

ABcDexter's answer is probably the most 'obvious', but here's an alternative:

> $5 (\text{mod } 1) + 1 (\text{mod } 1) = 4 (\text{mod } 1) = 0$

Comment: Aah here comes the MODular arithematic, interesting :)

Comment: Works (mod 2) too.