# Perfect Squares!

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

A question was asked in a [mental ability test](http://www.hiqora.com/round-2/) yesterday.

> Write **four distinct** numbers with these properties:
>    1. Sum of each pair is a perfect square.
>    2. Sum of all four is also a perfect squares.

Can you solve this?

Comment: No constraints were given.

Comment: For number A, B, C, D do I interpret the taskcorrectly as: Find A, B, C, D such that  (A+B), (A+C), (A+D), (B+C), (B+D), (C+D) and (A+B+C+D) are all perfect squares?

Comment: @BmyGuest Yes, that's absolutely correct interpretation.

Comment: Might not be too late to add `no-computers` tag for the sake of purity

Comment: @humn Agreed, although doing a good algorithm to test all, is not as straight forward neither, considering there is no other constraint.. (Testing in complex space with 4 variables seems a bit harsh, f.e....)

Comment: Indeed, @BmyGuest, and it would be valuable to see if a program were to find multiple solutions (if nobody figures out the complete set by hand)

Comment: @ABcDexter view my answer

Comment: I also wonder what the *smallest* possible number(s) is.

Comment: Your question made me revisit my algebra skills. Conclusion: I need a warm up.

Comment: Uh @abcdexter, shouldn't I get the accept because I got an answer first?

Comment: @ev3commander Although I've asked this in the chat room, but still, I'll reconsider the answers. You have done a lot of hardwork, i understand :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Took a long time but worth it.

I got two answers.

Ist set can be:

> -88,88,137,488

As:

> -88+88 = 0, a perfect square
> -88+137 = 49 = 7^2
>  -88+488 = 400 = 20^2
>  88+137= 225 =15^2
>  88+488 = 576 = 24^2
>  137+488 = 625 =25^2
>  and finally,
>  -88+88+137+488=625=25^2

2nd set

> -88,344,1177,2792

As:

> -88+344 = 256 = 16^2
> -88+1177 = 1089 = 33^2
> -88+2792 = 2704 = 52^2
> 344+1177 = 1521 = 39^2
> 344+2792 = 3136 = 56^2
> 1177+2792 = 3969 =63^2
> and
> -88+344+1177+2792=4225 = 65^2

Answer (score 19):

Below is a way to construct many solutions to the problem:

> It's easy to see that we can write:
>  $A = (a^2+b^2-d^2)/2$
>  $B = (a^2-b^2+d^2)/2$
>  $C = (d^2+b^2-a^2)/2$
>  $D = c^2+(d^2-a^2-b^2)/2$
>  where
>  $e^2+b^2 = f^2+a^2 = d^2+c^2 = g^2$
>
>  So we need square numbers that satisfy this equation, and can then find appropriate values of $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$. Note that the total number of odd values amongst $a$, $b$, and $d$ must be even (zero or two). So we need to find a square number that can be expressed as a sum of two squares in at least three different ways. We can achieve this by using complex numbers for evaluation.
>
>  Consider $125^2$. Now, we can express this in the form $5\times5^2\times5^3$. Noting that $5 = 1^2+2^2$, $5^2=3^2+4^2$, and $5^3=11^2+2^2$, we can find appropriate pairs by evaluating
>
>  $±(1+2i)(3±4i)(11±2i)$
>
>  which has values $75-100i$, $117+44i$, and $35+120i$ (the fourth case gives 125). So if we let
>  $a=75$
>  $b=44$
>  $c=120$
>  $d=35$
>  $e=117$
>  $f=100$
>  $g=125$
>
> Then we get
>  $A = 3168$
>  $B = 2457$
>  $C = −1232$
>  $D = 11232$
>
>  Note that we can choose other products, to get different sets of values. For instance, ev3commander's first solution comes from $325^2 = 5^4\times13^2$, which can be written as $325^2 = 5\times65\times325$, with $5=1^2+2^2$, $65=1^2+8^2$, and $325=1^2+18^2$.
>
>  ev3commander's second solution comes from $65^2 = 5^2\times13^2 = 5\times13\times65$, with $5=1^2+2^2$, $13=2^2+3^2$, and $65=4^2+7^2$.
>
>  wrangler's solution comes from $25^2 = 5\times5\times25$, with $5=1+2^2$ and $25=3^2+4^2$.

Comment: If this is secretly a computer solution, you have a brilliant computer!

Comment: "It's easy to see that we can write" - we have very different definitions of easy

Comment: @Holloway - it's just a matter of very basic algebra. Start with writing out, for instance, A+B=a^2, A+C=b^2, A+D=c^2, and B+C=d^2. These four are enough to define A, B, C, and D. Continue with B+D=e^2, C+D=f^2, and A+B+C+D=g^2, and you get the sum-of-squares relationships, too.

Comment: Wow, that is beautiful solution. What a shame I gave up so early.

Answer (score 18):

It may be

> Since it is mental arithmetic and no restrictions.
>  $3, -3, 4i, -4i$

since:

> a) $3 -3 =0$
>  b) $3 + 4i = (2 + i)(2 + i)$
>  c) $3 - 4i = (2 - i)(2 - i)$
>  d) $-3 + 4i = (1 + 2i)(1 + 2i)$
>  e) $-3 - 4i = (1 - 2i)(1 - 2i)$
>  f) $4i - 4i = 0$

and also:

> $3 - 3 + 4i - 4i =0$

Comment: Great, I should have thought about it(complex numbers) during test. Those two hours passed too fast.

Comment: I was thinking of complex numbers, too. But is your solution valid by the definition of ['perfect square'](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_number)? (2-i) is not an integer...

Comment: Good point BmyGuest! My answer is not valid!

Comment: @BmyGuest - wikipedia's a little inaccurate, a "perfect square" in integers is as described, but you can have a "perfect square" in other integral domains. The ones given by Tom are in the Gaussian Integers. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#As_perfect_square_Gaussian_integers

Comment: @GlenO thanks. Always good to learn something new.

Comment: Thx GlenO and BmyGuest - my line of internal thinking was actually confused between (3,4,5) & (9,16,25) triples -  I hope to read more on algebraic numbers. Also ABcDexter - that is some mental ability test - Gauss would have been good for it - and you too!

Answer (score 10):

Here we can have...

> $a+b=38025=195^2$
>  $a+c=15625=125^2$
>  $a+d=8281=91^2$
>  $c+d=67600=260^2$
>  $b+d=90000=300^2$ 
>  $b+c=97344=312^2$
>  $a+b+c+d=38025+67600=15625+90000$
>   $=8281+97344=105625=325^2$

Numbers:

> $a= -21847$
>  $b=59872$
>  $c=37472$
>  $d=30128$

> seriously no computers, besides posting this. I did all this work on paper. It's possible.

Comment: +1. a+b+c+d here does not equal a perfect square (though it seems all the other combinations do)

Comment: my calculation for d was wrong. Fixing...

Comment: @Inazuma, a+b+c+d=105625=325^2…

Comment: Many brownie points to you

Comment: Your calculations are perfect. (edited a bit)

Answer (score 8):

- **Before continuing, let me say we have some trivial answers,  like $a=b=c=d=0$ or $a=b=0, c=3^2, d=4^2$. But I am looking for an answer with no zero values.**

Since we have four integers say, $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$. We have 6 pairs of them, $$A_1=a+b=A^2\\
A_2=a+c=B^2\\
A_3=a+d=C^2\\
E_3=b+c=D^3\\
E_2=b+d=E^2\\
E_1=c+d=F^2$$

as you may easily see, if $a+b+c+d$ be a square, say $G^2$, the number should be presented as sum of two square in more than 2 different ways.

$$G^2=a+b+c+d=A_1+E_1=A_2+E_2=A_3+E_3$$

Since $5$ and $13$ are the smallest primes of the form $4k+1$, therefor their multiplication, $65$ is the smallest number in which its square could be shown in more than two ways as sum of two squares. so $G=65$, and $G^2=4225$.

Now, lets remember $65^2$ could be written as sum of two square in 4 different ways:
$$65^2=4225\\
=256+3969=16^2+63^2\\
=625+3600=25^2+60^2\\
=1089+3136=33^2+56^2\\
=1521+2704=39^2+52^2$$

Since, I am whishing to find smallest answer for the problem, I should find which 3 (out of the 4 possible) pairs of square shall I chose.

Whitout further ado, let me show the answers
$$a=-495\\
b=1120\\
c=1584\\
d=2016$$

I found them by solving the following linear equation.

$$\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 }\times \pmatrix{a \\ b \\ c \\ d}=\pmatrix{A_1 \\ A_2 \\ A_3 \\ 65^2}$$
By selecting $A_1=625$, $A_2=1089$, and $A_3=1521$.

Happy 2016! I bet no one can find a set of 4 nontrivial value each of which have an absolute value smaller than $2016$. ☺

Comment: 1. I suppose you didn't see my answer first, right? 2. @wrangler already made a solution with all numbers in range (-2016, 2016)

Comment: "some trivial answers" - they're ruled out anyway by the distinct number rule.

Comment: +1 This is by far the easiest, most thorough answer to understand. There are lots of other answers, but this is the only one which clearly shows how you did it *without* a use of a computer.

Comment: This answer can be improved by explaining significance of the 4k+1 form of a prime number, as well as by demonstrating how to find (16,63), (25,60), (33, 56), (39, 52) pairs without computer. The latter mentioned in passing in Glen's answer.

Comment: "I bet no one can find a set of 4 nontrivial value each of which have an absolute value smaller than 2016"...seriously??  View my answer

Comment: @wrangler - one could argue that -88 and 88 aren't "distinct" in this situation. But yes, if you allow two numbers to have the same magnitude, your solution has the smallest magnitudes.

Answer (score 5):

One solution (if these numbers do not have to be positive, but OP said 'no constraints'). 
Also interpreting 'each pair' as in two separate pairs, i.e. (A, B) and (C,D) but not (A,C) or (B,D):

> $-x, x, y, -y$

Then:

> $ -x + x = 0 = 0^2$
>  $ -y + y = 0 = 0^2$
>  $ -x + x -y + y = 0 = 0^2$
>  where $x \neq y.$

I am going to see if I can find a more interesting combination, however.

Comment: Shame on the anonymous down voter.

Comment: Didn't vote, but I guess the DV voted after the clarification above, which makes your answer invalid. Hence downvote. (It is *not* a good answer.)

Comment: Please don't argue over the votes, and show me the Maths to do it. *I'd love to get some Pythagorean triples which fit into this system*.  P.S I upvoted O:)

Comment: @ev3commander Yes I already did.

Answer (score 4):

An epic one (kinda small) Also bonus for including 2016?

> $a=-495$
>  $b=2016$ yay
>  $c= 1120$ 
> $d=1584.$

Squares

> $65^2 = 4225=33^2+56^2=25^2+60^2=39^2+52^2$
>  
>  So, $a+d=1089=33^2$
>  $b+c=3136=56^2$
>  $a+c=625=25^2$
>  $b+d=3600=60^2$
>  $a+b=39^2=1521$
>  and $c+d=2704=52^2$.

Comment: You are posting some good answers, once i cross check all will accept one of the above :)

Answer (score 3):

ANSWER OVERLOAD

> -1980, 4480, 8064, 6336. Squares: 2500, 14400, 6084, 10816, 4356, 12544. squares of 50,120,78,104, 66 and 112. Total is 16900 or 130^2

> -864, 2464, 3465, 2160. Squares are 1600, 5625, 2601,4624, 1296, 5929. Squares of 40;75;51;68;36;77. Total is 7225 or 85^2

> -3419.5,4644.5; 5365.5, 9044.5. Squares are 1225;14400;1936;13689;5625; 10000. Squares of 35;120;44;117;75; 100. Total is 15625=125^2

Comment: At last, fractions!

Answer (score 2):

Why is everyone using large numbers? A simple solution is:

> 1, 8, 8, 8

You have sums for pairs:

> 9 & 16

while for all of the numbers is:

> 25

Comment: the Q says 'distinct'

Comment: As Jon states it, the problem was to find distinct numbers. The "solution" (1,8,8,8) is too obvious.